# Parsing the result of a web service

Tags: c#, parsing, service, deserialization

I have a web service and after calling it and fetching the result, I can't put results in an array of objects.

I'm using C# code and looking for a way for deserializing these results and hope somebody can help or tell me the way I should go.

Note: the single quote mark is replaced with `\u2019` so is there a table for special characters unicodes that can be found in the returned result such that I can replace them?

Thanks..

Comment: Looks like it's just JSON - have you tried using a JSON parser (e.g. json.codeplex.com)?

Comment: Thanks, that's the correct way. I'll try it, although it didn't work with one of my team. I don't know where the problem is. Maybe he didn't use it as supposed, or something wrong with the input he gave to the parser!!

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there a reason no one suggests using the .NET Framework serializers? No one ever seems to recommend `JavaScriptSerializer`..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I don't know about anyone else, but in my case it's primarily lack of experience - I've never used JavaScriptSerializer, so I'm reluctant to explicitly recommend it. Equally, I don't know anything *wrong* with it either.

Answer (score 1):

I use JavaScriptSerializer for working JSON data. (Normally, I add this [custom converter](https://github.com/tekpub/mvc3/blob/master/Source/VidPub.Web/App/Infrastructure/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs) I learned about from TekPub to get DateTimes to format as a nice string. )

It's really easy to use:

```
    using (var web = new WebClient())
    {
        var url = "http://[fill in your url here]";
        var jsonStr = web.DownloadString(url);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        IDictionary<string, object> objGraph = (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);

        Console.WriteLine(objGraph["has_next"]);
        Console.WriteLine(((Object[])objGraph["object_list"]).Length);
    }
```

In the example code, I'm working with the result as a dynamic object but if you knew th structure you could get the results mapped back to a typed object instead.

Comment: Oh that's nice, liked the 'web.DownloadString(url)' it worked with me on WP7.